# How to set language in googleVis

Tags: r, r-markdown, googlevis

I am rendering a table report via googleVis version 0.5.10. My data contains date columns. When I render table report I get date columns formatted with the full month names in them. By default they are using default language, which is Russian for me.

How do I set language in googleVis to English, so it could be passed to google?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late for an answer, but I've only recently seen your post while googling for the same issue with an app I developed, where dates where expressed in italian (eg. 24 June 2017 was shown as 24 Giu 2017).
In my case I was rendering a `gvisLineChart` and setting the **gvis.language** parameter (`options=list(gvis.language="en",` ) didn't work.

I was able to make it work by specifying the date format in the statement used to build the dataframe I need.

```
chart3 <- aggregate(geoData[,c("slug")], by=list(format(as.Date(geoData$timestamp),"%d %b %Y")), FUN=length)
```

Since you haven't posted any code I'm not able to suggest more solutions to your problem, but I guess you should try to set format as well.